# Is it possible to change language?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've got a Nintendo 2DS system and Pokémon X. I now have a nice progress in the game, but I'm playing in German localization.

As I'm keen on playing competitive online, I also experience that most of the up-to-date sites are English written. No problem, but it's always a pain the [Froslass](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Froslass_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) to look for attack, item and miscellanious names in German.

I read in the interwebs that changing the language is only possible with wiping the game data. I would like to avoid this.

**Is there a way to change the language of the Pokémon X/Y module without erasing the game data?**

Comment: Not that I know of. The game itself gives the warning that you won't be able to change the language, so it might not be possible :(

Comment: Yes, read that, too. That's why I acceptet @StrixVaria answer. I hoped that maybe a patch or vis major changed that. :) Thanks though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the language after you start the game. If you want to change the language, you will have to erase your save data and start over from scratch.

Comment: I find this really, really annoying as well, for what it's worth.

Comment: That's what i know, too, and it should be the correct answer. Just let me wait a couple of hours/days til I'll mark it. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, when you start the game, he shows a warning for you about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you have a Powersave Action Replay system. It's about $20 and there is a code on there that will change the language of your game. However, I don't know if it will change any foreign named Pokemon in your boxes, but it will change the attacks and items to the English version if you do choose English.